# Compare Dates in Angular 2

Tags: datetime, angular, typescript1.7

I'm trying to figure out how best to compare dates in Angular 2 and TypeScript 1.8.7.

Given:

```
startDate: Date;
endDate: Date;

if(this.startDate.getUTCMilliseconds() === this.endDate.getUTCMilliseconds()){
     //do stuff here
} else {
     // do something else here
}
```

This will return an error like "startDate.getUTCMilliseconds is not a function..."

Does somebody have a best practice?  Thanks,

Comment: `{{+startDate == +endDate}}` (unary `+`) doesn't work in binding expressions though https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7964

Comment: See also https://plnkr.co/edit/EFsbEl?p=preview (3 and 4 demonstrated how unary `+` works differently when applied in template (no effect) and in code.

Answer (score 1):

Date object method to get milliseconds is called `getTime`.

Comment: Nice try.  But, we're dealing with javascript dates.  This is way too logical.  If there's some interference from Typescript, I don't have a clue.  Intellisense is comfortable with getTime, but Chrome is screaming that getTime is not a function.

Comment: `someDate.getTime()` works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: @LargeDachshund Did you solve this? I have the same problem

Comment: Wouter, I have not.  I needed this logic for field validation.  It became such a pain that I gave up.  What's so painful is that you'd think something like time would be quite determinant.  Instead, there are tons of formatted dates that pass for a date.  So, I took a pass on this issue.  Thanks for making me relive this nightmare.

Comment: `getTime` and any other method of `Date` type does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can compare Date objects directly, with operators like `<`, `>`, and `==`.

```
this.startDate == this.endDate
```

Comment: While this appears to be the right answer, I can't give the "green check mark" because of this test: if this.endDate = new Date("0001-01-01T00:00:00") and this.startDate is the minimum date, the condition should return true.  Instead, the condition returns false.  This is fitting because dates in Java and javascript are inscrutable.

Comment: @LargeDachshund What test?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's irrelevant and not what you asked for, but use angular-moment / momentjs. Dates in JS are a complete mess.

Comment: Dates in general, seem like a complete mess.  If there's a best practice for boxing/unboxing dates in TypeScript objects, I'm all ears.  That's what I'm driving at.